# Using CSV data with awk

Tags: awk, csv

I am trying to find a way to take the individual data from a CSV file, and use it as a variable within a grep or awk command. Either seems appropriate but I'm not sure how to tell it to do this appropriately.

For example, I have a dataset in TSV format that looks like this:

```
ID    Name    Eye Color 

1     Bill    Blue 
2     Sam     Blue 
3     Fred    Brown 
4     Joe     Brown 
5     Ted     Blue 
6     Bob     Brown
```

This is not the actual dataset, but behaves the same way. This is the entire protein binding database, the TSV is 300MB with millions of entries, and dozens of columns, so I can't cleanly include the real thing.

I want to make a file containing the rows with individuals who have blue eye, so I have created a CSV file which is made up of the "ID" column, which in this case would look like this:

1, 2, 5

This CSV containing the "ID" was generated using the "Grep" command to search for the key term.

I ultimately want a TSV file which looks like this: 1 Bill Blue 2 Sam Blue 5 Ted Blue

But I cannot seem to figure out how to do it. I can create it individually for each entry using awk or grep and including the ID number as a criteria, however the CSV I'm using has 1200 entries so I would like to automate this process.

Below is code that will produce the desired result for a single entry, but I want to use the ID numbers to search automatically.

The BindindDB_All.tsv is my source file, with several million entries. This will produce a TSV called "new.tsv" and contains the entire row of the BindindDB_All.tsv file where the ID (in column 1) equals 66106.

```
awk '$1 == 66106' BindingDB_All.tsv >> new.tsv
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
awk '$1 == ID.csv' BindingDB_All.tsv >> new.csv
```

where it would read each ID, print the line to new.csv, then read the next ID and do the same.

The CSV file contains 1200 search terms, to be compared with several million possibilities each with a unique ID. I need it to ONLY search column 1, as it will find the ID within other variables in each row.

To summarize, I need it to look in column 1 of the row, compare it to the first number in my CSV file, and see if it is a match. If it is not a match, then it needs to check the next row in column 1, and so on until it finds the match. When it does find the row where column 1 matches the CSV first data point, I want it to output the row. Then I want it to repeat for the second entry in the CSV, until it has found all 1200 rows.

Any ideas? It sounds like a loop problem but I don't know how to make that work either.

EDIT:

Since people still seem willing to help, let me try to answer the questions that have been posted.

Here are the first 6 entries of my real data, containing ID numbers which will be used as search parameters.

```
66106     
66107    
66108    
66109     
66110    
50127715
```

There are no column names, no other data. These are values which I want to search for individually in a different file, a TSV. I have also mispoken regarding the TSV size, I have a 4 GB TSV, which compresses to 300 MB. The file contains more entries than any of my programs allow it to even view. Below is an example of a single entry out of several million. I NEED all of this data to be pulled at once, so trimming it is not an option.

50127715    CCCC(CCC)c1nc2N3[C@H]4CCC[C@H]4N=C3N(C)C(=O)c2[nH]1 InChI=1S/C18H27N5O/c1-4-7-11(8-5-2)15-20-14-16(21-15)23-13-10-6-9-12(13)19-18(23)22(3)17(14)24/h11-13H,4-10H2,1-3H3,(H,20,21)/t12-,13+/m1/s1    CSRSQFSFDXYRFV-OLZOCXBDSA-N 50073697    5-methyl-2-(1-propylbutyl)-(6aR,9aS)-3,4,5,8-tetrahydrocyclopenta[4,5]imidazo[2,1-b]purin-4-one::CHEMBL280307   Phosphodiesterase   1   Bos taurus          60                          ChEMBL  10.1016/s0960-894x(98)00681-7   9990447         Ho, GD      Silverman,  L       Bercovici,  A       Puchalski,  C       Tulshian,   D       Xia,    Y       Czarniecki, M       Green,  M       Cleven, R       Zhang,  H       Fawzi,  A   Schering-Plough Research    Institute   http://www.bindingdb.org/bind/chemsearch/marvin/MolStructure.jsp?monomerid=50073697 http://www.bindingdb.org/jsp/dbsearch/PrimarySearch_ki.jsp?energyterm=kJ/mole&tag=pol&polymerid=49000914&target=Phosphodiesterase+1&column=ki&startPg=0&Increment=50&submit=Search  http://www.bindingdb.org/jsp/dbsearch/PrimarySearch_ki.jsp?energyterm=kJ/mole&tag=r21&monomerid=50073697&enzyme=Phosphodiesterase+1&column=ki&startPg=0&Increment=50&submit=Search          44272162    103967010       CHEMBL280307                ZINC28221715    1   MGSTATETEELENTTFKYLIGEQTEKMWQRLKGILRCLVKQLEKGDVNVIDLKKNIEYAASVLEAVYIDETRRLLDTDDELSDIQSDSVPSEVRDWLASTFTRKMGMMKKKSEEKPRFRSIVHVVQAGIFVERMYRKSYHMVGLAYPEAVIVTLKDVDKWSFDVFALNEASGEHSLKFMIYELFTRYDLINRFKIPVSCLIAFAEALEVGYSKYKNPYHNLIHAADVTQTVHYIMLHTGIMHWLTELEILAMVFAAAIHDYEHTGTTNNFHIQTRSDVAILYNDRSVLENHHVSAAYRLMQEEEMNVLINLSKDDWRDLRNLVIEMVLSTDMSGHFQQIKNIRNSLQQPEGLDKAKTMSLILHAADISHPAKSWKLHHRWTMALMEEFFLQGDKEAELGLPFSPLCDRKSTMVAQSQIGFIDFIVEPTFSLLTDSTEKIIIPLIEEDSKTKTPSYGASRRSNMKGTTNDGTYSPDYSLASVDLKSFKNSLVDIIQQNKERWKELAAQGEPDPHKNSDLVNAEEKHAETHS      Calcium/calmodulin-dependent    3',5'-cyclic    nucleotide  phosphodiesterase   1A  PDE1A_BOVIN P14100  Q08E30,Q28063

I am not sure how to make this read as a TSV within this box, but 50127715 is the first column, the ID column. I want to have my initial CSV file, containing the ID numbers of interest, search the large TSV one ID number at a time within the first column. If the number is contained within the first column, I want it to write that line to a file, then search for the next ID. I want all of the results in a single file.

I'm sure that throughout all of my steps to get here there's an easier way to do this, but I am clearly not sure how to make this clearer. I want it to search the large TSV for "66106" within column 1, and when it finds the line to write the entire line into a file. Then search for "66107" and once it finds it, adds it to the same file. This way I have a single file, Can be a CSV or TSV, with 1200 entries rather than several million.

Comment: Why not just parse the TSV directly?  `awk -F '\t'` will separate input fields by tabs.  And indeed by default `awk` will separate fields by coniguous whitespace. So to get all blue-eyed people (and preserve the header), you just need `awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" } NR==1 { print } NR>1 && $3 = "Blue" { print }'`.

Comment: I tried running this command on a sample file called "test.tsv", with the same input as listed above, however it produced an unusual output. It just replaced all of the Eye Colors with "Blue" while everything else stayed the same.

Comment: `$3 = "Blue"` should be `$3 == "Blue"`. The former is an assignment, the latter is a comparison.

Comment: Is this a CSV or TSV?

Comment: The file I'm trying to search is a TSV, the file with the parameters is a CSV.

Comment: Dishing out the information about your requirements a breadcrumb at a time isn't a good approach to getting a good solution. Please [edit] your question to provide a more truly representative example of what it is you're trying to do. Include a TSV file, a CSV file, and the expected output files you expect given that as input. Make sure you cover all your use cases, e.g. whether all matches are against values in 1 column or different matches in different columns, etc. See [ask].

Comment: I see this is the same advice you got in comments under [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/600801/133219). If you're not sure what it is we're asking you for, please do ask us for more information.

Comment: I'm trying here, I'm a biologist so I'm struggling here. If my latest edit is still not sufficient I need some advice on how to change it.

Comment: It's very simple: You want to extract lines from a TSV. So show us such a TSV that's minimal (certainly less than 10 lines of less than 10 fields per line) but truly representative of your real data. You want to use data from a CSV to identify which lines in the TSV to select. So show us such a CSV that, again, is minimal but truly representative of your real data. You want to output a TSV that's a subset of the input TSV after processing with data from the CSV. So show us the TSV you'd expect to be output given the TSV and CSV you provide as input. [edit] your question to provide all 3 files.

Comment: I suspect that you’ve probably given up on us, but in case you ever come back and see this: (1) You say that you (want to) create a CSV file that lists the ID numbers of all the people who have blue eyes, *and then go from that* to a TSV file that lists ID numbers and names of all the people who have blue eyes.  It seems like you could skip the middle man and go directly from the complete 300 MB input file to the output file that lists complete records for all the people who have blue eyes by a command as simple as ``grep "Blue" BindingDB_All.tsv``.  This should look familiar to you … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  because you posted it in your previous question. So, are you trying for a complicated solution to a simple problem because you don’t understand the simple solution? Or is the problem really more complicated than what you’re telling us? (2) You say “The CSV file contains 1200 search terms”. I guess that, when you say ‘‘search terms’’, you mean ID numbers. And you seem to be saying that there can be several million distinct (unique) ID numbers, so I guess that means that they can range above 1000000 (one million), probably 2000000 (two million) or higher. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  So each ID number can be a seven-digit number.  Add a comma and a space, and each entry in the CSV file can be 7+1+1 = 9 characters long.  So the CSV file can be 1200×9 = 10800 characters long — and that’s all in a single line!? (You also suggested that it could be a thousand times worse than that.) It’s unfortunate that your input file has dozens of columns, but that may be an unavoidable consequence of the nature of your data.  Putting over a thousand values (over 10000 characters) in a single line seems like a very bad idea. Do you really need to do it this way? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Or do you just think that this is the best way to get your *real* desired result, and you’ve gotten this far, and now you’re stuck?  (3) You say “I ultimately want a TSV file which looks like this: 1 Bill Blue 2 Sam Blue 5 Ted Blue”.  The trouble is, that doesn’t look like a TSV file.  Do you want a TSV file that looks like `1       Bill    Blue` (newline) `2       Sam     Blue` (newline) `5       Ted     Blue`?  (4) We know that your examples are not your real data, and you repeatedly refuse to show us even a sample of your real data. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Can you at least answer this question: Are both files in order by ID?  Or might you, somewhere in that 300 MB, have 174238 followed by 174236?  (5) Please try hard to read our comments and give us what we ask for.  I also posted comments on your previous question.  You misread my comments and didn’t give me what I asked for.  Please don’t go away believing that we’re useless; we can be very helpful if you help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may find this in the future, I have a solution. The first thing I did was convert the TSV to a CSV using:

```
sed 's/\t/,/g' filename_with_tabs > filename_with_commas.csv
```

Then to search my file code I was looking for is:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {h[$1] = $0; next} {print $0,h[$1]}' file1 file2 > new_file.csv
```

This will search the first column for the text contained in a separate CSV. In this case, "file1" is the file to search and "file2" contains the strings to search for. Both of those files are CSV format.

This produced a separate CSV file which contained all of the lines within file1 which had a certain ID in column 1 that matches one of the IDs contained in file2.

I hope that helps someone someday, because this has wracked my brain for weeks. I didn't even get the solution myself, my boss had to show it to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'\t' '(NR==1) || ($3=="Blue")' file
ID      Name    Eye Color
1       Bill    Blue
2       Sam     Blue
5       Ted     Blue
```

It sounds like what you're really trying to do, though, is create a new file per ID which, assuming the IDs are unique like in your example, would be:

```
awk -F'\t' '{ out="out_" $1 ".txt"; print > out; close(out) }' BindingDB_All.tsv
```

or if you want each output file to include the header:

```
awk -F'\t' '
    NR==1 { hdr=$0; next }
    { out="out_" $1 ".txt"; print hdr ORS $0 > out; close(out) }
' BindingDB_All.tsv
```

Comment: I have editted it for clarity, but I really only want 1 file containing those names. Due to the nature of the data being enormous I just tried to make an example set for demonstration purposes, but I'm new to programming so I'm not sure if I'm properly expressing what I need.